# Inner class is not public error when instantiating new inner class

Tags: java, inner-classes, access-modifiers

I have this class

```
package com.rafael;

public class Vehicle {

    public class InnerVehicle {
        InnerVehicle() {
            System.out.println("This is InnerVehicle");
        }
    }
}
```

And in the main function

```
import com.rafael.Vehicle;

public class VehicleTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Vehicle v = new Vehicle();
        Vehicle.InnerVehicle iv = v.new InnerVehicle();
    }
}
```

But this always gives me that error:

> java: InnerVehicle() is not public in com.rafael.Vehicle.InnerVehicle;
>   cannot be accessed from outside package

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the inner class `public static`

Otherwise you need an object of your outer class to creat an instance of the inner as Tim Biegeleisen already mentioned

And make the constructor of your inner class `public` too

Something like:

```
public class Vehicle {    
    public static class InnerVehicle {
        public InnerVehicle() {
            System.out.println("This is InnerVehicle");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yea, It was because of the constructor not being `public`.

Answer (score 0):

You were referring to the nested class incorrectly.  You can only instantiate the inner class in the context of the containing class:

```
Vehicle v = new Vehicle();
InnerVehicle iv = v.new InnerVehicle();
```

The syntax you were using was for a static nested class, in which case your code would look like this:

```
public class Vehicle {
    static public class InnerVehicle {
        InnerVehicle() {
            System.out.println("This is InnerVehicle");
        }
    }
}

Vehicle.InnerVehicle iv = new Vehicle.InnerVehicle();
```